# What is the example reference threshold for each component of a LAB image?

Tags: python, opencv, lab-color-space

I'm doing a project of face skin detection. I need to replace each pixel in a face image with a black pixel if the image intensity is less than some fixed constant T, or a white pixel if the image intensity is greater than that constant.

I know in opencv, cv2.threshold takes two arguments, First argument is the source image, which should be a grayscale image. Second argument is the threshold value which is used to classify the pixel values.

Can anybody tell me how to threshold color images by designating a separate threshold for each of the LAB components of the image and then combine them with an AND operation?

Example threshold ranges would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an sample code i wrote:

```
import cv2

color_image = cv2.imread("lena.png")
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(color_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
L,A,B=cv2.split(lab_image)  

th, th_image = cv2.threshold(L,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#cv2.imshow("original",color_image)
#cv2.imshow("l space",L)
cv2.imshow("th imaged",th_image)


# wait until escape is pressed
while True:
    keyboard = cv2.waitKey()
    if keyboard == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

here is the official doc:

> `cv.Threshold(src, dst, threshold, maxValue, thresholdType) → None`
>
> Parameters:
>
> - src – input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).
>
>   - dst – output array of the same size and type as src.
>   - thresh – threshold value.
>   - maxval – maximum value to use with the THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV thresholding types.
>   - type – thresholding type (see the details below).

the code will generate you these three images:

Original:

[image]

L-Space of the LAB Convertion:

[image]

and finally a simple threshold example:

[image]

a rly good tutorial can be found here for tresholding: [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)

Comment: How can I convert the "th_image" image back to Lab colorspace?

Comment: it isnt possible, cause the informations of each pixels are lost, but you can still work with the L image...

usally the workflow ist to threshold the image.. find some interessting parts and finally to them on the original image... so the thresholded image is only temporary used